# LISTEN/NOTIFY on AWS Aurora/postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, pg-notify

I am hoping to implement a trigger that fires a notify on table change in PostgreSQL, but I am unable to find any definite answer to if it would work in a cluster.

Does PostgreSQL listen/notify work on AWS Aurora (both provisioned and serverless), and can I expect all clients to receive notifications regardless of what instance they are connected to?

If yes, are there any major performance concerns?

Thanks :)

Comment: It should be quite simple to spin one up and test. Someone might have already tried.

Comment: I don't see any performance penality with aurora postgres 13.6 (serverless 2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The best AWS Documentation implies - YES, it does work**

Specifically for Aurora Serverless, there is an advisory that "LISTEN/NOTIFY" is NOT RECOMMENDED. This implies that it's possible with Aurora Serverless but not advisable. It also implies that normal RDS LISTEN/NOTIFY does work and is ok to use.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html

> Currently, certain SQL queries and commands, such as cursors with hold
> (DECLARE name ... CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR query); session-level advisory
> locks; temporary relations; and asynchronous notifications (LISTEN,
> NOTIFY commands) prevent scaling and are not recommended

**My own quick test on AWS shows - Yes, it does work**

1. Launch Instance with Public Access

[image]

...

[image]

2. Allow Traffic

[image]

3. Run command in dbeaver

[image]

Note: This test doesn't show a successful receipt of a notification. That will need a quick console application to test that.

Comment: Note that they removed that the doc reference is for serverless 1. For serverless 2 they removed the advice : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.html

Comment: I also have tested it on serverless 2 with postgres 13.6